# docker volume won't persist

Tags: docker, docker-compose

this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

When I start and stop the mongo container I lose all data.
What am I missing out on ?

Comment: Have you created the volume manually?

Comment: No I didn't specify anything extra

Answer (score 1):

Try running `docker volume create dbdata` in order to create a persistent volume, redeploy your stack and it should work *after* that. I.e. the first reboot will cause a data wipe, but after that it should persist.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it wasn't working but it is now solved

After running my docker-compose file I see the `mydata` volume when I run `docker volume ls`. 
That volume persists through container destruction.